# Google Cloud Storage : Accessing blob pages by Index returned by Storage.list in Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have following function in Java to get list of blobs from cloud storage.

```
Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName,
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3" + "/" + "b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304" + "/" + "requests/")
        );
```

I want to use start and end offset for accessing specific blobs with index.

for e.g.

```
        Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName,
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3" + "/" + "b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304" + "/" + "requests/")
                Storage.BlobListOption.endOffset("80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3" + "/" + "b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304" + "/" + "requests/" + "79679696979")
        );
```

Now it will return Page but I want to get last 5 results for e.g. let's say it returns

```
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79179696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79279696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79379696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79479696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79579696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79679696979/123.txt
```

But I would like to get only last 5 results for e.g. and in this order.

```
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79279696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79379696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79479696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79579696979/123.txt
80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3/b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304/requests/79679696979/123.txt
```

### Problem

Is there a native way to achieve this or some way to transform Page to ArrayList so that I can do this manipulation myself ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library provided by google which can help us achieve this easily.

### Library

com.google.http-client:google-http-client

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client

### Uses

```
import com.google.api.client.util.Lists;


Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName,
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3" + "/" + "b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304" + "/" + "requests/")
                Storage.BlobListOption.endOffset("80448357-e1b5-44e1-9554-b5b7321b42c3" + "/" + "b5ac6031-6593-4ae3-9d76-6605cfb36304" + "/" + "requests/" + "79679696979")
        );
List<Blob> blobList = Lists.newArrayList(blobs.iterateAll());
// Can do manipulation and get result the way we want.
```